# Unity URP Water Shader working in Scene View, in the Preview Window... but all white in Game View?

Tags: unity, shaders, rendering, water, unity-urp

I downloaded an URP compatible Water Shader from the asset store.

First I tried it with **2022.1** but for some reason while in **Scene View it looked great**, in **Game View it's all white**. (Sometimes a watery colour emerged for a few frames at some places).

Suprisingly if I selected the camera in Scene View, the little **preview was working** as well, even though it was a bit ugly.

Then I tried it with **2020.3** and it works now **both in Scene and Game View!**

But if it works in 2022.1's Scene View... It could be working somehow in the Game View as well, right?

I've tried disabling/enabling Fog, Depth Texture, Opaque Texture, Anti-Aliasing, Post Processing, but to no avail.

This is the asset in question but I encountered this issue with multiple URP water shaders: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/urp-stylized-water-shader-proto-series-187485

Could you help me please?

[image]

[image]